# CloudFormation 'package' with file path variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

The CloudFormation `package` command traverses CloudFormation templates, uploads local references to S3, and creates a new template referencing the S3 resources. ([documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudformation/package.html))

So, if I have something like:

```
StatusLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties: 
      Code: ../main/java/status/target/status-lambda-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
      Description: This Lambda function for new messages
```

The `package` command transforms it to

```
StatusLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties: 
      Code: https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/stack/b3dba2bcc4401e10000000000.template
      Description: This Lambda function for new messages
```

This is great. The problem is integrating with my client's Jenkins build server. When I am building and deploying locally, the lambda source is at `../main/java/status/target/status-lambda-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`. The automated build server places the artifacts somewhere else.

Is there any way I can use the same template for both? Could I somehow plug in the file path at build time? I had hoped that `package` would support something like the following, but it doesn't appear so; the command doesn't seem to execute any functions.

```
StatusLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties: 
      Code: !Ref LambdaJarPath
      Description: This Lambda function for new messages
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to overcome the issue would be a **find-and-replace processing** of the lambda template in your pipeline before executing `package` command.

For example, your template file could be

```
StatusLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties: 
      Code: <LambdaJarPath>
      Description: This Lambda function for new messages
```

and then in Jenkins you could execute `sed` (or similar command) to replace `<LambdaJarPath>` with the correct path to artifact. Once this is done, then you would proceed with with `aws cloudformation package`.